# check for jsonArray if null or not

Tags: java, android, json

i am trying  to check  json Array  to get name of author and if null i need to give  me unknown author 
this json array

```css
{  
   "kind":"books#volumes",
   "totalItems":604,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "kind":"books#volume",
         "id":"6tLAyQLSzG0C",
         "etag":"wtUTTM0nDQA",
         "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/6tLAyQLSzG0C",
         "volumeInfo":{  
            "title":"Android for Work",
            "subtitle":"Productivity for Professionals",
            "authors":[  
               "Marziah Karch"
            ],
```

and this my java code

```
 // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(bookJSON);

        // Extract the JSONArray
        // which represents list of title of book ant author name.
        JSONArray bookArray = root.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length(); i++) {

            // Get a single booka t position i within the list of books
            JSONObject currentBook = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            // Extract the value for the key called " title"
            String title="";
            if(volumeInfo.has("title"))
            { title = volumeInfo.getString("title");}
            JSONArray authors= volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
            String author = "";


                for (int j = 0; j < authors.length(); j++) {
                    if(authors.length()==0){
                // Convert the authors to a string
                author = authors.getString(j);}else{author="unknown";}}
```

i can get title of book  but name of author always unknown i do not know why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this condition `if(authors.length()==0)`

This should be :

```
JSONArray authors= volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
String author = null;
if(authors.length() > 0) {
    author = authors.getString(authors.length() - 1);
} else {
    author="unknown";
}
```

Comment: @A Edwar  i already accept  did you mean ? or tell me how i accept

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik it's not a big deal if you couldn't do it that's Ok, I'm just glad i could help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145754/discussion-between-a-edwar-and-mohammedragabmohammedborik).